# OpenGL - 2D Overlay Transparency

Tags: opengl, transparency

I am in the process of creating simple 2D program.  I wanted to know if what I want to achieve is possible using some OpengGl alpha/blending techniques.

Essentially, I want to have a scene with 2 images, one on top of the other. I would then like to be able to pass a circle over the top of the first image, which would make that image transparent so that you could see the image behind.  I have made a basic image (VERY BASIC) to visualise what I am trying to achieve.

Image Link [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/scHS8.png)

Comment: Yes, it is possible to do this with OpenGL.

Comment: Could you perhaps suggest a method for achieving this?

Comment: It depends on your OpenGL skills and on the OpenGL version you're using. As I'm mainly using shaders, this is a trivial task ... but using the old fixed function pipeline will be a lot more complicated.